# how to get :bwipe *.ext to wipe everyone matching the wildcard in vim

Tags: vim

I often want to wipe all buffers loaded with a given extension (usually .rej files produced by patch).  Just doing :bw[!] *.rej will complain if there is more than one match.  Does anyone have any good tips?  Currently I either repeatedly use :bw *.rej + tab-complete or, if there are a lot of buffers, use :ls and :bw a set of buffers by number.

Comment: sounds like you might need to write (or find) a plugin to do this.  :bwipe only takes a `bufname` as you have experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Globbing in vim is a bit difficult (apart from for files on the file system).  Therefore, the best way seems to be to convert the wildcard into a regular expression and then check each buffer in the buffer list to see whether it matches.  Something like this:

```
" A command to make invocation easier
command! -complete=buffer -nargs=+ BWipe call BWipe(<f-args>)

function! BWipe(...)
    let bufnames = []
    " Get a list of all the buffers
    for bufnumber in range(0, bufnr('$'))
        if buflisted(bufnumber)
            call add(bufnames, bufname(bufnumber))
        endif
    endfor
    for argument in a:000
        " Escape any backslashes, dots or spaces in the argument
        let this_argument = escape(argument, '\ .')
        " Turn * into .* for a regular expression match
        let this_argument = substitute(this_argument, '\*', '.*', '')

        " Iterate through the buffers
        for buffername in bufnames
            " If they match the provided regex and the buffer still exists
            " delete the buffer
            if match(buffername, this_argument) != -1 && bufexists(buffername)
                exe 'bwipe' buffername
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction
```

It can be used as:

```
:BWipe *.rej
```

or:

```
:BWipe *.c *.h
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I ended up going with a very low-tech solution (I personally like to modify vim as little as possible so that I am at home on any machine):

I added a mapping:

> :map <C-f> :bw *.rej

Then I repeatedly press
<C-f> <Tab> <CR>

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  I get round the "at home at any machine" issue by keeping the whole of `.vim` (or vimfiles on Windows) and vimrc under available-anywhere version control.  That way any changes I make get pushed to whichever machine (or USB stick) I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit around the corner, but works for me, with a lot of files:

1. :mksession!
2. :q
3. vi Session.vim
   a) remove all 'badd' lines with files you do not want
   b) :wq
4. vim -S Session.vim # restart with the state you had, but without the files

Answer (score 0):

Do `CTRL-A` to insert all the matches of the pattern in front of the cursor. See `:help c_CTRL-A`. For example, if you have the files `a.rej`, `b.rej`, and `c.rej` loaded, then doing

```
:bw *.rej<C-A>
```

will leave you with

```
:bw a.rej b.rej c.rej
```

Then you can press Enter to wipe those buffers.